# Extracting and evaluating math functions

Tags: regex

I have an expression string:

```
10+5*Math.Tan(40)+Math.Cos(0)+40*Math.Sin(90)
```

I want to extract these mathematical function (using regex etc) and evaluate their value:

```
tan(40),sin(90)
```

so that the expression string becomes:

```
10+5*(-1.11)+1+40*1
```

How to go about it?

Comment: Evaluate? With what programming language or math tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to find the functions in your string. First group will be the Word behind the "Math." (Tan, Cos, Sin) and second group will be, what's inside the brackets (40, 0, 90):

```
Math\.(\w+)\((.*?)\)
```

After finding them, you can evaluate and replace them.